# How to save n:m associations with Sequalize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Given these three models:

```
const User = sequelize.define('tbl_user', {
    name: DataTypes.TEXT,
});
const Project = sequelize.define('tbl_pproject', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});
const UserProject = sequelize.define('tbl_user_project', {
  role: Sequelize.STRING
});
User.belongsToMany(Project, { as: 'projects', through: UserProject });
Project.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'users', through: UserProject });
```

If I receive this JSON data representing a user, how can I save it in the database?

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: 'Bob'
   userProjects: [{
      projectId: 33,
      role: 'author'
   }, {
      projectId: 42,
      role: 'contributor'
   }]
}
```

**Update**

Here is the [SSCCE of the issue](https://github.com/papb/sequelize-sscce/pull/26), my problem is that it tries to create models that already exist.

The gist of the problem is this:

- There can be many users
- There can be many projects
- A user can have roles in many projects
- Many users can share the same project

The problem is this : Sequalize tries to force one user per project. The association fails in reverse. That is, this fails:

```
User.belongsToMany(UserProject, { as: 'userProjects', through: Project });
Project.belongsToMany(UserProject, { as: 'userProjects, through: User });
```